# iOS converting short to bytes of length 2

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a short variable and i want to convert it to 2 bytes in iOS

```
short num = 10;
char *bytes;
```

Now I want to convert this num value into bytes

Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be like this
    char * bytes  = malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);

```
bytes[0]  =  (char)(num & 0xff);
bytes[1]  =  (char)((num >> 8) & 0xff);
```

EDIT : After all the comments below..

```
char * bytes  = malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);

bytes[0]  =  (char)(num & 0xff);
bytes[1]  =  (char)((num >> 8) & 0xff);
bytes[2]  = '\0' ; // null termination

printf("strlen %d", strlen(bytes));
printf("sizeof %d", sizeof(bytes));
```

Now you can understand the difference..

Comment: but how to convert char[] to char *?

Comment: you can create a new char pointer, and pass the address of bytes. or you can declare bytes as char pointer and do malloc to allocate memory for it..

Comment: i declared a char pointer with 2 bytes but still its size shows four bytes

Comment: char* ret = malloc(2);
    ret[0] = (char)(a & 0xff);
    ret[1] = (char)((a >> 8) & 0xff);
    return ret;

Comment: you might want to use `char *ret = malloc(2 * sizeof(char)); `

Comment: i tried ur code but its not working. Its size is again returning 4 bytes

Comment: sizeof(bytes) will only give you 4 , since you are printing the size of the pointer, which will always be int..

Comment: Normally the size of a pointer is 4 bytes (size of an int, big enough to hold an address).

Comment: That doesn't mean the size of the memory it is pointing to (the memory you allocated using malloc) has 4 bytes..

Comment: so then how to get size of char *??

Comment: that is how much bytes it contains?

Comment: Just try `printf("%d", sizeof(char));` and `printf("%d",sizeof(char*));` and see the result.. You can see the difference..

Comment: And to find the size of a char array in C, you must use strlen() function. But it only works on null terminated strings. It will not work on your case, since you only have 2 bytes in the array, and there is no null termination..

Comment: pls tell me how to get no of bytes a char * contains?

Comment: Please check my edit.. You will have to read up your C skills, especially about array and pointer..

Comment: but what in case if i can't null terminate my char *

Comment: how to get the no of bytes used by my chat * variable

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can do it like this

```
char buf[2];
short num = 10;
sprintf(buf, "%d", num);

// buf[0] = '1'
// buf[1] = '0'
char c = buf[0];
```

Johan

Comment: Shouldn't "buf" be a size of 3 then (null terminator)?

Answer (score 1):

> First of all thanks to **baliman**, It is working for me after some changes

```
NSString *myStr = @"2";

char buf[2];

sprintf(buf, "%d", [myStr integerValue]);

char c = buf[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and 2 bytes is the same thing if short is 16bit, so all you need is to type cast it to whatever you want.. Anyway, if you use this a lot you could use union:

```
union ShortByteContainer {
    short shortValue;
    char byteValue[2];
};
```

With it you can transition from short to byte or the other way around:

```
ShortByteContainer value;
value.shortValue = 13;
char byteVal1 = value.byteValue[0];
char byteVal2 = value.byteValue[1];

value.byteValue[0] = 1;
value.byteValue[1] = 2;
short shortVal = value.shortValue;
```